# C# : how to share a YouTube video on Google Plus?

Tags: c#, .net, google-plus

I want to share YouTube videos on Google Plus using Google Plus API which i found  [here.](https://developers.google.com/+/downloads)

Please tell me where i can found step by step guide or tutorial for that ?

Or please tell me how can i share YouTube videos on Google Plus ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Google+ API is read only right now. You can not pragmatically share anything to it. Your best option is to use the [+1 button](https://developers.google.com/+/plugins/+1button/).